# External Shared files list details in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: asp.net, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I used Microsoft Graph API for getting onedrive shared files and folder. I am getting files which is shared with me, but I want files and folder which is shared with other people or external to organisation.

For Microsoft Graph API: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_sharedwithme

Answer (score 0):

There is a [shared](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/shared) resource on the [driveitem](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem). You should be able to filter on that property to find files and folders shared with other people.

**Update** - As of today, the shared property is only available on the OneDrive consumer accounts.

Comment: thanks, could you please provides the filter on that property or API link with filter on that.

Comment: Hello @HimanshuNTatariya, the shared property is currently available on OneDrive consumer accounts. We are working on this functionality for OneDrive for Business. If you don’t mind, can you tell us how you plan to use the shared property in your project?

Comment: I want only list out the Shared files and folder with public, with in organisation and outside the organisation and also want user, and then I will handle in one of my project.

Comment: Could you please know how to convert business to consumer account ?

Comment: @HimanshuNTatariya I don't know of a conversion path from business to consumer account. With that said, if your timeline supports it, you could work out how this functionality works in a consumer account in preparation for when it becomes available for business account.

Comment: Has the API been updated? I am still not able to get the list of users with whom a given document is shared.

Comment: Please search for and vote on existing feature requests, or create a new feature request, using the [Microsoft Graph User Voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests)

Comment: @HimanshuNTatariya, "getting onedrive shared files and folder" - how did you find this? I have similar query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700031/find-the-shared-with-me-folder-id-drive-id-and-files-id-onedrive-microsof, Please help me on this