# Find the "Shared with me" Folder Id (Drive Id) and Files Id - OneDrive, Microsoft Graph, Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

My clients shared some onedrive folder with me which contains 5 Files, I want to find the drive-Id, File-Id, so that I can download using python scripts, Script reference: [Not able to download files from inside folder, OneDrive, Microsoft Graph, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61695577/not-able-to-download-files-from-inside-folder-onedrive-microsoft-graph-python/61698658#61698658)

I am trying below script:

```
requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Access_Token}).content

requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Access_Token}).content
```

but I am getting my files details only.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the uri `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe` first and get the response data. In the response, we can find the `id` and `driveId`(the "driveId" is under "remoteItem" -> "parentReference") of the shared file. And then use the api below to download its content.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{driveId}/items/{id}/content
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I got blank in value ("value":[]): b'{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)","value":[]}'

Comment: @SPy Which api did you request to get the blank value ?

Comment: @Hurry Shen I have hit https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe

Comment: It was shared from other domain, not in same domain, Like Client Shared file to their Partner

Comment: @SPy Can you see the shared file in your onedrive "Shared with me" in browser ?

Comment: @Hurry Shen No, Its not showing in "Shared with you", Client Shared their onedrive folder to my microsoft account and I am login using client URL that I got mail, not in my Drive. may be this is the issue

Comment: @SPy It seems the client just share the link with you and the file doesn't exist in your onedrive. So we may not access the file according to some api.